# Make Google Chrome Browser Icon Flash on task bar

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, notifications

I am building a web app when the user finds a match, the browser icon in the task bar will flash orange. Could I achieve this with HTML and JavaScript code?

Shown in the picture below (but for the Google Chrome icon):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome only flashes when the browser announces an alert, so printing an alert with javascript could be a workaround for the intended result. Keep in mind it also only does this if you are not currently focused on chrome. Hit run and quickly tab out to see what I mean.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 alert("Flash you Chrome, flash!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```